# How to make Play Framework WS use my SSLContext

Tags: web-services, ssl

I'm using Play 2.3.7 with Scala 2.11.4, Java 7. I want to use Play WS to connect to an HTTPS endpoint, that requires client to present its certificate. To do it I create my own SSLContext:

```
  val sslContext = {
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12")
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(clientKey), clientKeyPass.to[Array])
    val kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm)
    kmf.init(keyStore, clientKeyPass.to[Array])

    val trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks")
    trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(trustStoreFile), trustStorePass.to[Array])
    val tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm)
    tmf.init(trustStore)

    val ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")
    ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers, tmf.getTrustManagers, new SecureRandom())
    ctx
  }
```

I know, that the SSLContext is valid, because I can use it with URLConnection successfully:

```
  def urlConnection = Action {
    val conn = new URL(url).openConnection()
    conn.asInstanceOf[HttpsURLConnection].setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory)
    conn.connect()
    Ok(scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(conn.getInputStream).getLines().mkString("\n"))
  }
```

But when I try one of two ways below I get java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException.

```
  def ning = Action.async {
    val builder = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
    builder.setSSLContext(sslContext)
    val client = new NingWSClient(builder.build())
    client.url(url).get() map { _ => Ok("ok") }
  }

  def asyncHttpClient = Action {
    val builder = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
    builder.setSSLContext(sslContext)
    val httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient(builder.build())
    httpClient.prepareGet(url).execute().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    Ok("ok")
  }
```

I also get the same exception when I go after suggestion of Will Sargent and use NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder with parsed config (note, that config references exactly the same values, the hand-crafted sslContext does).

```
  def ningFromConfig = Action.async {
    val config = play.api.Configuration(ConfigFactory.parseString(
      s"""
          |ws.ssl {
          |  keyManager = {
          |    stores = [
          |      { type: "PKCS12", path: "$clientKey", password: "$clientKeyPass" }
          |    ]
          |  }
          |  trustManager = {
          |    stores = [
          |      { type: "JKS", path: "$trustStoreFile", password: "$trustStorePass" },
          |    ]
          |  }
          |}
          |# Without this one I get InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
          |ws.ssl.disabledKeyAlgorithms="RSA keySize < 1024"
       """.stripMargin))
    val parser = new DefaultWSConfigParser(config, play.api.Play.application.classloader)
    val builder = new NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder(parser.parse())
    val client = new NingWSClient(builder.build())
    client.url(url).get() map { _ => Ok("ok") }
  }
```

How to make it work with Play WS?

Comment: I accepted Will's answer because it is likely the best possible one to the original question. That it didn't work in my case is a separate thing, but it needed to be about some obscure details of this particular SSL setup which is now impossible to replicate. I ended up using Spray HTTP client that time (Akka HTTP now) to work around the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a client certificate from application.conf as defined in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/KeyStores and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ExampleSSLConfig -- if you need to use a custom configuration, you should use the parser directly:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play-ws/src/test/scala/play/api/libs/ws/DefaultWSConfigParserSpec.scala#L14

to create a config, then the Ning builder:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play-ws/src/test/scala/play/api/libs/ws/ning/NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilderSpec.scala#L33

which will give you the AHCConfig object that you can pass in.  There's examples in the "Using WSClient" section of https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS.

Comment: I went after your suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't work - please see the updated question

Comment: You need to turn on ws.ssl.debug and look at why the connection was terminated.  See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/DebuggingSSL

Comment: One of the differences that I see there is server_name extension in SSL hello present in the successful case. Can you force Play WS to put it there?

Comment: You need to determine why your connection is failing first.

Comment: Where would you suggest to start that diagnosis? I just turned debug trace on and compared outputs between the positive and negative case. Lack of server_name extension in the negative case was something I noticed in the diff.

Comment: I would suggest using the guides http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html and http://www.smartjava.org/content/how-analyze-java-ssl-errors and https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https